# Application Layers and Contracts

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, n-tier-architecture, aggregateroot

What is the prefered communication: `IAggregationRoot` marker is stored in `Domain Layer` and `Data Access Layer` references it in `IRepository` contract or vice versa?

**EDIT**

I looked at `Tim Maccharty's` (http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0470147563,descCd-authorInfo.html) implementation of `repository pattern` and `unit of work` pattern. It's very useful for unit-testing purpose to have own/fake implementation of `IUnitOfWorkRepository`. I got confused a little bit more with where do I store such contracts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored in Domainlayer. From my point of view you don´t want to  depend on the infrastructure/DAL layers from your domainLayer.

The second best approach I´ve tried is to have a third separate assembly like DDDBaseFramework that u can resuse.